# Does docker-machine can only mount /c/Users on windows?

Tags: docker, docker-machine

But I want to mount /d because I like to put my projects on /d.

Comment: The question is clear and it's a common issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[docker-machine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/) uses a boot2docker.iso VM image, based on [TinyCore](http://tinycorelinux.net/)

The [original boot2docker project mentioned](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/master/README.md#virtualbox-guest-additions) that you can mount other folders with, at runtime:

```
mount -t vboxsf -o uid=1000,gid=50 your-other-share-name /some/mount/location
```

[Issue 1814 of docker-machine](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/1814#issuecomment-139070770) suggests that, and it seems to work.

Comment: I has try to add this script to rc.d/, but the script disappears when I restart the machine.

Comment: @JieMinXia try first to type it manually once you have ssh to the boot2docker VM. If that works, what I usually do an `ssh cp` before the interactive `ssh`: for example (not related to sharing folders, but the same idea applies): https://github.com/VonC/b2d/blob/1a3a147bb59a209f1cedd0c37c4a2cddef3d6ea5/b2d.bat#L20-L24