# How do i get postgres data to persist using docker-compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, boot2docker, docker-compose

I keep losing my data when i restart my docker, here is my docker-compose.yml

```
postgres:
  image: postgres
  volumes:
    - /data/myproject/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  ports:
    - '15432:5432'
  environment:
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mypassword
    POSTGRES_USER: mypassword
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using boot2docker, you need to know that [only `/Users` is shared between the host (a Mac for instance) and the docker VM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33797933/6309).

That means when you restart your VM, anything stored *outside* `/Users` (like `/data/myproject/postgres`) would be lost.

Try mounting a volume with a host path which is actually shared between your host and your VM.

Comment: thanks for the response, so you mean if m host machine is an ubuntu vm i need to map it to any dir in /home/<vm-username>/  ?

Comment: @MrMixin No: your host machine would be a Mac or a Windows if you need a boot2docker VM.

Comment: @MrMixin If your host was Ubuntu, you wouldn't need a boot2docker VM. Even if your host is using an Ubuntu VM, you wouldn't need boot2docker since you would do docker directly within the Ubuntu VM.

Comment: So on a MAC system with boot2docker would he put his path as `/Users/data/myproject/postgress` instead of `/data/myproject/postgres`

Comment: @DrManhattan Yes, that is the idea.