# docker compose won't mount the external volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I mount my folder `/workspace/ap_news/esdata`  to elastic_search container, however, I cound't see any created index/ files on the host(mac os) folder.

The created indexes by elastic search only saved in the container.

It couldn't be accessed on my host os(Mac OS)

## compose.yml

```
elasticsearch:
  image: elasticsearch:1.7.1
  hostname: elasticsearch
  ports:
    - "9200:9200"
    - "9300:9300"
  volumes:
    - /workspace/ap_news/esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
```

## update

I've already mount the host folder to virtualbox

[image]

Comment: When you do a `docker machine ssh default`, do you see `/workspace` content?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a boot2docker VM (even with docker machine), make sure your host local folder is mounted first on that VM.

By default, [a boot2docker (Tinycore-based) VM will mount only `/Users`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33797933/6309), nothing else.

Ssh to that vm (docker machine ssh default, for instance) and do:

```
mount -t vboxsf -o uid=1000,gid=50 your-other-share-name /workspace/ap_news/esdata
```

Comment: @newBike I believe the boot2docker.iso only shows /Users, not other mounted folders.

Comment: @newBike see https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/master/README.md#virtualbox-guest-additions