# share windows folder (other than c/Users/) with docker container (using docker windows client)

Tags: windows, docker, docker-machine

Using docker client, is there a way to share a folder in windows with a docker container without having to first share the folder via the Virtual Box VM.

Have understood the need of having a double slash from [this](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/846) and [this](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/12751)

Ran the following command from the docker client for windows

```
docker run -it -v //F/devfolder:/development/windev <imagename> <cmdname>
```

but when did a ls on /development/windev , it turned out it was empty.

I did not have any problem when I tried mounting the c/Users/username folder via the following command

```
docker run -it -v //c/Users/username/desktop:/development/windev <image> <command>
```

and the windev folder listed the contents as I would expect it to be

Tried sharing F/devFolder via Virtualbox GUI and gave full access but still the contents of the folder is not listed.

[I am not using boot2docker but docker-machine]

Is it not possible to share any other folder than the c/Users/ folder? If yes, anything else I need to do to ensure that I can see the contents of the mounted folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not only you have to mount it in your VirtualBox, but [you also have to instruct, in your boot2docker TinyCore session that you want that folder visible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33797933/6309) (once you have done a `docker-machine ssh yourMachine`):

```
mount -t vboxsf -o uid=1000,gid=50 your-other-share-name /some/mount/location
```

I know that you are using `docker-machine`, and not `boot2docker`, yet `docker-machine` is still using a `boot2docker.iso` VM image based on TinyCore, so this command still applies.

Comment: Also this might be helpful to not confuse the share-name with a folder path http://serverfault.com/questions/674974/how-to-mount-a-virtualbox-shared-folder

Comment: @JohnSam yes. Was able to get the windows folder mounted correct.

Comment: @But without use VirtualBox UI, I can use only docker-machine to mount other folders?

Comment: @JohnSam I guess so to mount the folders without VBox UI though I used the VBox UI.It involved 2 steps. First use the Virtual box UI to configure a share folder. Steps I did are as follows:
1. First share the folder in Virtual box UI. Share name in VBox is DevEnv

2.docker-machine.exe ssh default 'sudo mkdir --parents //f/v1/Dev'

3.docker-machine.exe ssh default 'sudo mount -t vboxsf DevEnv //f/v1/DevEnv'

Then run the docker container

4.docker run -it -v //f/v1/DevEnv:/development/windev <imagename> bash

Comment: I need to use only docker-machine code in shell, not virtualbox ui. It woks? I don't think so.

Comment: @JohnSam with shell command, that would be using VBoxManage: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders

Comment: No, I would use Docker like vagrant. Vagrant uses vagrant folder automatically. How with Docker?

Comment: @JohnSam Docker, use in a VM managed by VirtualBox, automatically uses `C:\Users` (as `/C/Users`).

Comment: I have all my project in other drive like D:/projects. Can I use a symlink? Because I need to work on files with my editor.

Comment: @JohnSam No: symlink is not supported by the tiny-core based image used by VirtualBox as a VM for docker. You need to mount `D:/project` both in VirtualBox (VBoxManage) and in TinyCore (see my answer above)