# Setting up Gitlab using Docker on Windows host, issue with shared folders

Tags: docker, virtualbox, gitlab, windows-server-2012-r2, docker-toolbox

**TLDR;**

Does anyone know how to solve the "Failed asserting that ownership of "/var/opt/gitlab/git-data" was git" error?

**Background:**

I want to set up the [Gitlab Docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/gitlab-ce/) on WindowsServer2012R2 running Docker toolbox, version 17.04.0-ce, build 4845c56.

**Issue/Question**

I can't get the shared folder to work properly on the D drive of the server. I read that I needed to add the folder to the VirtualBox VM, which I did via the settings/shared folder menu in the VB GUI. I set a name "gitlab" to the path "D:\data\gitlab" then checked auto-mount, make permanent, and set it to full access.

[image: VM Shared Folder Settings]

I started the docker machine and ran "docker-machine ssh $machine-name". I noticed that there was no /media directory and so I added a folder at the home directory (/home/docker/gitlab) and then mounted the shared folder using the following command I found in several forums:

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf gitlab /home/docker/gitlab
```

At this point I can add files to the Windows host directory or the Docker VM and it seems to work fine and the test files show up.

Now when I spin up the Gitlab Docker image, I use the following command modified from their documentation:

```
docker run --detach --hostname gitlab.example.com --publish 80:80 --name gitlab --volume /home/docker/gitlab:/etc/gitlab:Z --volume /home/docker/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab:Z --volume /home/docker/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab:Z gitlab/gitlab-ce
```

Now I know that it appears to be writing to the shared drive, because all of these files are generated, but then it crashes after a few seconds and I receive the following error log.

[image: Files Generated when Running Gitlab Docker]

Error Log:

```
Thank you for using GitLab Docker Image!
Current version: gitlab-ce=9.3.6-ce.0

Configure GitLab for your system by editing /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb file
And restart this container to reload settings.
To do it use docker exec:

  docker exec -it gitlab vim /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
  docker restart gitlab

For a comprehensive list of configuration options please see the Omnibus GitLab readme
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/README.md

If this container fails to start due to permission problems try to fix it by executing:

  docker exec -it gitlab update-permissions
  docker restart gitlab

Installing gitlab.rb config...
Generating ssh_host_rsa_key...
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Your identification has been saved in /etc/gitlab/ssh_host_rsa_key.
Your public key has been saved in /etc/gitlab/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:GyFlf9tl7ZuEbuE+dwZUYiyahdsRzpC1T7kwyUvoD+o root@gitlab.example.com
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 2048]----+
|        o .+oo   |
|       o .o*+o+.o|
|      . . o*@+oo+|
|       . o+o.Oo= |
|        S o o++..|
|         + oo + o|
|        o   .+ + |
|       .    o. .o|
|        E    .o..|
+----[SHA256]-----+
Generating ssh_host_ecdsa_key...
Generating public/private ecdsa key pair.
Your identification has been saved in /etc/gitlab/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.
Your public key has been saved in /etc/gitlab/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:Kb99jG8EtMuTSdIuqBT3GLeD1D0wwTEcQhKgVJUlBjs root@gitlab.example.com
The key's randomart image is:
+---[ECDSA 256]---+
| .o+=*=+=+       |
|..  oo..=..      |
|.  E   . * .     |
|    o + +.B      |
|     +.BS* *     |
|    . +o= B .    |
|   . .  .o =     |
|    .    o. +    |
|        . .+.    |
+----[SHA256]-----+
Generating ssh_host_ed25519_key...
Generating public/private ed25519 key pair.
Your identification has been saved in /etc/gitlab/ssh_host_ed25519_key.
Your public key has been saved in /etc/gitlab/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:lVxpu0UoyNPWVY6D9c+m/bUTyvKP6vuR4cTOYwQ0j+U root@gitlab.example.com
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ED25519 256]--+
|       . o +.=o..|
|        +.=o@o.+ |
|         o+=.Eo o|
|         .  + .o.|
|        S    B  +|
|            B o= |
|            .Oo +|
|           ..o+.+|
|          .+*+.oo|
+----[SHA256]-----+
Preparing services...
Starting services...
Configuring GitLab package...
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/runsvdir-start: line 24: ulimit: pending signals: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/runsvdir-start: line 34: ulimit: max user processes: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/runsvdir-start: line 37: /proc/sys/fs/file-max: Read-only file system
Configuring GitLab...

================================================================================
Error executing action `run` on resource 'ruby_block[directory resource: /var/opt/gitlab/git-data]'
================================================================================

Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
------------------------------------
Failed asserting that ownership of "/var/opt/gitlab/git-data" was git
---- Begin output of set -x && [ "$(stat --printf='%U' $(readlink -f /var/opt/gitlab/git-data))" = 'git' ] ----
STDOUT:
STDERR: + readlink -f /var/opt/gitlab/git-data
+ stat --printf=%U /var/opt/gitlab/git-data
+ [ UNKNOWN = git ]
---- End output of set -x && [ "$(stat --printf='%U' $(readlink -f /var/opt/gitlab/git-data))" = 'git' ] ----
Ran set -x && [ "$(stat --printf='%U' $(readlink -f /var/opt/gitlab/git-data))" = 'git' ] returned 1

Cookbook Trace:
---------------
/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/gitlab/libraries/storage_directory_helper.rb:124:in `validate_command'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/gitlab/libraries/storage_directory_helper.rb:112:in `block in validate'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/gitlab/libraries/storage_directory_helper.rb:111:in `each_index'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/gitlab/libraries/storage_directory_helper.rb:111:in `validate'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/gitlab/libraries/storage_directory_helper.rb:87:in `validate!'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/gitlab/definitions/storage_directory.rb:35:in `block (3 levels) in from_file'

Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/gitlab/definitions/storage_directory.rb

 26:   ruby_block "directory resource: #{params[:path]}" do
 27:     block do
 28:       # Ensure the directory exists
 29:       storage_helper.ensure_directory_exists(params[:path])
 30:
 31:       # Ensure the permissions are set
 32:       storage_helper.ensure_permissions_set(params[:path])
 33:
 34:       # Error out if we have not achieved the target permissions
 35:       storage_helper.validate!(params[:path])
 36:     end
 37:     not_if { storage_helper.validate(params[:path]) }
 38:   end
 39: end

Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/gitlab/definitions/storage_directory.rb:26:in `block in from_file'

ruby_block("directory resource: /var/opt/gitlab/git-data") do
  params {:path=>"/var/opt/gitlab/git-data", :owner=>"git", :group=>nil, :mode=>"0700", :name=>"/var/opt/gitlab/git-data"}
  action [:run]
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  default_guard_interpreter :default
  block_name "directory resource: /var/opt/gitlab/git-data"
  declared_type :ruby_block
  cookbook_name "gitlab"
  recipe_name "gitlab-shell"
  block #<Proc:0x000000054a99a8@/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/gitlab/definitions/storage_directory.rb:27>
  not_if { #code block }
end

Platform:
---------
x86_64-linux
```

Does anyone know how to solve the "Failed asserting that ownership of "/var/opt/gitlab/git-data" was git" error? I'm still somewhat new to Docker/setting up Gitlab, so it's very possible I could have overlooked something simple. I've spent several hours Googling this, and it seems that others also have a lot of issues getting shared folders to work from Windows using the Docker Toolbox, so hopefully this will help others as well.

Comment: Did you used the right uid/gid? https://stackoverflow.com/a/33935328/6309

Comment: @VonC I tried to remount with the uid/gid in your referenced post, but it didn't work (I got the same error). I just came across this [post](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/README.html#windows-mac-error-executing-action-run-on-resource-ruby_block-directory-resource-data-gitlab), so I'm thinking now that it is just not possible to do it the way that I was approaching it, and the recommended process is to create an NFS mount instead of using the VirtualBox mount, so that's what I'll try doing next.

Comment: OK Don't forget to post an answer if you find a solution.

Comment: @VonC I haven't solved this yet, still new to a lot of the pieces, but I've posted a new question on setting up nfs here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45172466/4271437

Comment: NFS was a dead end. In the end, I have a 2 prong solution. 

1.) For the persistent volumes, use a second virtual drive that is located on the D drive (note: because docker machines are read-only, this will look like it's mounted since it's in the fstab, but it won't be. Either manually mount it after ever docker machine restart, or make a startup script with the proper mount commands.).

2.) For backups, you can use a simple mounted folder, since gitlab doesn't need any special permissions.

Comment: OK, interesting. You can post that as a solution, and even accept your own solution. That will help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Background**

One solution (maybe not the best) for those of us stuck in a world without native docker, is to use vdi drives and shared folders. The vdi drive can live on an drive we want (which is important if you don't want to use the C drive) and is used to allow the Gitlab docker the ability to chown anything it wants, so this is where we'll store the persistent volumes. The downside is that a vdi is not as transparent as a simple shared folder, thus for backups, a shared folder makes things a little bit easier/transparent.

**Disclaimer**

I'm not an expert on any of this, so please use caution and take what I say with a grain of salt.

**Steps to perform**

*Create a new vdi drive and shared folder on any drive you'd like*

1. Turn off your docker machine you want to use for gitlab
2. In virtualbox go into the settings on your docker-machine, then **Storage**, and click  **Add Hard Disk** icon, then **Create new disk**
3. Select **VDI (VirtualBox Disk Image)** and click **Next**
4. Select **Dynamically allocated** and click **Next**
5. Select the name and location you want to store the vdi by clicking the folder with green carrot symbol, then select the max size the vdi can grow to, and click **Create**
6. Now in the settings menu, switch to **Shared Folders** and click **Adds new shared folder** icon
7. Create a **gitlabbackups** folder to where ever you want and select **Auto-mount** and **Make Permanent**

*Now partition and format the drive*

1. Start/enter the docker machine (either use VBox  window or `docker-machine ssh <your docker machine name>` from cmd prompt)
2. Run `fdisk -l` to list the available drives, and if you've only mounted the one extra vdi drive, you should see something like */dev/sdb*
3. The next steps are **irreversible**, so perform it at your own discretion: enter command `fdisk /dev/sdb` then `n` for new partition, `p` for primary, and `1`
4. Now format the new partition (you might need sudo as well): `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1`

*Run docker with persistent volumes on second vdi and backups in shared folder*

Sample Dockerfile:

```
FROM gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y cron

# Add a cron job to backup everyday
RUN echo "0 5 * * * /opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create STRATEGY=copy CRON=1" | crontab -
# For an unknown reason, the cron job won't actually run unless cron is restarted
CMD service cron restart && \
    /assets/wrapper
```

Sample docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.0"
services:
  gitlab:
    build: .
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      # These volumes are on the vdi we created above
      - "/mnt/sdb1/etc/gitlab/:/etc/gitlab"
      - "/mnt/sdb1/var/log/gitlab:/var/log/gitlab"
      - "/mnt/sdb1/var/opt/gitlab:/var/opt/gitlab"
      # This volume sits in the shared folder defined above
      - "/gitlabbackups:/var/opt/gitlab/backups"
    cap_add:
      # These seem to be necessary for the mounted drive to work properly
      # https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities
      - SYS_ADMIN
      - DAC_READ_SEARCH
```

Because there seems to be an issue with auto mounting the vdi, use a startup script, for example (assuming you used a D drive, just replace anything inside <...> as needed), sample run.bat:

```
@cd /d D:\<path to docker-compose.yml, assuming it's on the D drive>
@docker-machine start <docker machine name>
@FOR /f "tokens=*" %%i IN ('docker-machine env <docker machine name>') DO @%%i
@docker-machine ssh <docker machine name> sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/sdb1
@docker-compose build
@docker-compose up -d
@REM If the docker machine was completely off, running only 'docker-compose up -d' will 
@REM not mount the volumes properly. Stopping and restarting the container results in 
@REM the volumes mounting properly.
@docker stop <gitlab container name>
@docker start <gitlab container name>
@pause
```

Note: the gitlab container name can be found by running `docker-compose up` once and then `docker ps -a` to check it, but it's usually follows the convention `<directory compose file is in>_<name in the compose file, e.g. gitlab here>_1`

Assuming all went well and you change the stuff in the <...>'s above for your situation, you should be able to run the batch file and have gitlab up and running in such a way that it stores everything on the alternate drive, persistent working files in the vdi (to get around VBox POSIX limitations), and backups transparently stored in the shared folder.

Hope this helps other poor souls that don't have access to native docker yet.